# while loop runs one iteration regardless

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int cash,num10s,change;

    printf("please enter the amount you wish to withdraw\n");
    scanf("%d", &cash);

    num10s = (cash / 10);
    change = (cash % 10);
    printf("%d",change);

    while (change != 0);
    {
        printf("please enter a value in 10s\n");
        scanf("%d",&cash);
        change = (cash % 10);
    }

    printf("sucess\n");

    return (0);
}
```

even when the change value is 0, the while loop will still run one iteration. why is this and how can i mitigate this problem

Answer (score 4):

There's a typo in your code.
Change

```
while (change != 0);
```

to

```
while (change != 0)
```

The `;` after the `while` loop causes the loop to run infinitely, because
`while (change != 0)` can also be written as

```
while (change != 0) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a semicolon after the while loops closing parentheses.

Comment: Good answer, but probably you should expand your answer a bit more. +1 to be the *slow and steady* :)

Answer (score 1):

This is one of my biggest reasons to state that **you should not put curly braces on their own lines**

```
while (change != 0);
{ 
  printf("please enter a value in 10s\n");
  scanf("%d",&cash);
  change = (cash % 10);
}
```

Looks good, but really the semicolon after the while statement means this is the same as

```
while (change != 0) {
  // do nothing
}
printf("please enter a value in 10s\n");
scanf("%d",&cash);
change = (cash % 10);
```

If you only put your curly brace on the same line as it's keyword, then you would see a bigger difference between `while (...) {` and `function(...);` and would have had less of a chance of adding the semicolon which ended the "empty block" on the while loop.

Comment: While I am ranting about brace placement, `} else {` instead of a three line "else", I don't like to wear out my scroll bars and screens are wider than tall, so vertical space is at a premium.

Answer (score 1):

You have a semicolon at the end of while statement, which terminates the while statement at that line itself.  Change the while statement to`while(change! =0){}`